# C++: Manipulate file resources?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, resource-files, file-manipulation

Are there any WinAPI functions or so to manipulate file resources? 
I'd like to replace menu scripts, icons etc of system files like shell32.dll and shell32.dll.mui using C++, but I really have no idea how to get started on this. :/
I know that resource hacker has a command line interface, but I would really like to do it with C++ directly.

(Yes I'm aware of the risk that comes with manipulating system files.)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, yes there is. See this list of [Resource Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468902(v=vs.85).aspx).

Primarily you're looking at:

- [BeginUpdateResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648030(v=vs.85).aspx) to begin a batch update of resources
- [UpdateResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648049(v=vs.85).aspx) to update a particular resource
- [EndUpdateResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648032(v=vs.85).aspx) to finish updating and save the resources back to the file

For an example, see [Updating Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648008(v=vs.85).aspx#_win32_Updating_Resources).

Comment: It just doesn't work. :/ Resource Hacker does it more or less fine as long as you manually edit the script, click recompile and then overwrite the exe. But Resource Hacker's resource replacing feature fails.